# Is Azure SQL Elastic Pool the Right Choice for Having Separate SQl DB in DEV and PROD Environment

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-elasticpool

**When hosting a Web app using a SQL DB in Azure, we need a separate SQL DB in DEV & PROD environments.  Will using Elastic Pool be the better choice than Single database with 1 instance?**

It looks like the cost for 2 databases using Elastic Pool (1 for DEV & 1 for PROD) will be the same as the cost for Single database with 1 instance. **Does using Elastic Pool add more complexisty for Web App development?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does using Elastic Pool add more complexity for Web App development?

No, Elastic Pool doesn't add complexity infect it allows you to easily manage multiple databases which share same configuration and requires unpredictable usage demand.

> Will using Elastic Pool be the better choice than Single database with
> 1 instance?

This completely depends on your application requirement. Thought, I don't believe that your DEV environment DB required elastic pool because it's purpose only for Development which doesn't require scalability.

For PROD environment, Elastic Pool is a good option if your application has below use-cases. **Azure SQL Database elastic pools are a simple, cost-effective solution for managing and scaling multiple databases that have varying and unpredictable usage demands.**

[image]

Refer: [Elastic pools help you manage and scale multiple databases in Azure SQL Database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-pool-overview)

Comment: @UtkarshPat-MT: Thanks for providing the advice.  I still have a question on "Single database instance" plan.  If we need a database for DEV and one for PROD environment.  Do we need to pay for 2 DB instances? Assuming we want to keep the cost to the minumum and still have 2 DB instances for DEV ad PROD, could we simply use the "Elastice tool" plan and spin up 2 databases?

Comment: If you have 2 single database instance, you need to pay for both the DBs. You can definitely use elastic pool for DEV and PROD, there is no harm and the cost I guess would be same.